# Write or append string to a file. Getting read only file system error

Tags: android, file-io, android-sdcard, readonly, ioexception

First off I wanted to thank everyone for the help I've gotten on my last few questions. I've searched and done my best to figure out my latest problem but I've had no luck even after searching here. I'm trying to check to see if "heapFile.csv" exists and if it doesn't, to create the file and then write a string to it. If it does then I just want to append a string to it instead. I think what I have will do that but I keep getting an IOException along with it saying the file system is Read Only. I do have the manifest file changed to include accessing the sdcard and even used the android too to make a virtual sdcard in case that was the problem.

First here's the main activity java...

```
package com.loch.meaptracker;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private SeekBar happyBar, energyBar, anxietyBar, painBar;
private EditText noteField;
private DatePicker dPick;
private TimePicker tPick;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Button enterButton;
private int happyValue = 4, energyValue = 4, anxietyValue = 4,
        painValue = 4;
private static final String TAG = "heapApp";
private String Mood = "Blah";
final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // bars
        happyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.happinessBarID);
        happyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        energyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.energyBarID);
        energyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        anxietyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.anxietyBarID);
        anxietyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        painBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.painBarID);
        painBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        // end bars
        dPick = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        tPick = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        noteField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteTextFieldID);
        enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButtonID);
    } catch (Exception onCreateException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", onCreateException);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

// Bar listener methods
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int barValue, boolean hFromUser) {
    try {

        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.happinessBarID:
            happyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.energyBarID:
            energyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.anxietyBarID:
            anxietyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.painBarID:
            painValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        }
        String debugBarValue = "Happy is " + happyValue + ", Energy is "
                + energyValue + ", Anxiety is " + anxietyValue
                + ", Pain is " + painValue + ".";
        System.out.println(debugBarValue);

    } catch (Exception BarValueException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", BarValueException);
    }

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar happyBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar happyBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

// end Bar listener methods

// Enter Button listener Method

public void dialogPop(View v) {
    try {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        // set Title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("You entered: " + getMood())
                .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Okay",
                // When Okay button clicked the write mood string to file
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                try {
                                    // This is the string that should be
                                    // written to file
                                    String data = getMood();
                                    // This is the file that should be
                                    // written to
                                    File heapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/heapFile.csv");

                                    // if file doesn't exists, then create
                                    // it
                                    if (!heapFile.exists()) {
                                        heapFile.createNewFile();
                                    }

                                    // true = append file
                                    FileWriter heapFileWritter = new FileWriter(
                                            heapFile.getName(), true);
                                    BufferedWriter heapBufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(
                                            heapFileWritter);
                                    heapBufferWritter.write(data);
                                    heapBufferWritter.close();

                                    System.out.println("Done");

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        })
                // If they press either the cancel button or the back button
                // on their device (Same thing) then close the dialog and
                // give the user a chance to change what they've entered
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception buttonListenerException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", buttonListenerException);
    }
    return;
}

public String getMood() {
    try {
        int month = dPick.getMonth();
        int day = dPick.getDayOfMonth();
        int year = dPick.getYear();
        int minute = tPick.getCurrentMinute();
        String moodAntePost = "AM";
        boolean hourType = tPick.is24HourView();
        int moodHour = tPick.getCurrentHour();
        if (hourType == false && moodHour > 12) {
            moodHour = (moodHour - 12);
            moodAntePost = "PM";
        } else if (hourType == false && moodHour <= 0) {
            moodHour = 12;
        } else {
        }
        String noteText = noteField.getText().toString();
        Mood = "Happiness," + happyValue + ",Energy," + energyValue
                + ",Anxiety," + anxietyValue + ",Pain," + painValue
                + ",Date," + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ",Time,"
                + moodHour + ":" + minute + "," + moodAntePost + ",Note,"
                + noteText;
        System.out.println(Mood);
    } catch (Exception getMoodException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", getMoodException);
    }

    return Mood;
}

}
```

And the Manifest...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.loch.meaptracker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.loch.meaptracker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in this line:

```
FileWriter heapFileWritter = new FileWriter(
                                            heapFile.getName(), true);
```

*instead try this:*

```
  FileWriter heapFileWritter = new FileWriter(
                                                heapFile, true);
```

**explanation:**

heapFile.getName() refers to your file name so lets say heapFile.txt.
so when you ask FileWriter to write to this file. It doesn't know which file you are referring to. So it try to create the file. But wait! where it will create the file, as it has only the file name, not the complete path.

So even I am sure where it would think of creating the file, my guess is Root( I am not sure). Which is read-only hence the error.

> ```
> public FileWriter(String fileName,
>           boolean append)
>            throws IOException
> ```
>
> IOException - if the named file exists but is a directory rather than
>   a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be
>   opened for any other reason

Comment: My intention was that File heapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/heapFile.csv"); would tell it where to create the file, in this case wherever the external storage is on whatever device. I see you're probably right about the getname part. I'm not even sure why that's there. I'll try it and see if it works. Thanks much!

Comment: Just tried and it worked! Of course now I realize I have a few more things I have to do like closing the app once the file saves and making the path the file goes into a bit nicer and easier to find but aside from that I am DONE!!! YAY!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Also I would totally be voting this up if I had enough reputation to do so. >_<